# How to make an "application state" that is available for all Rails processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application that sometimes need to do a lengthy import of new data. While this import is running, the users should not be able to do any "write" tasks (ie. create new projects, etc.). The import job is running through DelayedJob

So basically I need the background task to do this:

1) Set application state to "importing - application is now read-only"

2) Run import

3) Set application state to "all ready - application is now functioning normally again"

Simply put - just a boolean flag, but a flag that should be globally available in all processes. The question is: What is best practise to implement this?

I could easily create an ActiveRecord model called ApplicationState with this flag as a field. However it seems a bit like overkill for this.

So any alternatives will be greatly appreciated.

/ Carsten

Comment: I'm using state machine for something similar, but I don't know is it the 'best practice': https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine

Comment: I also use state_machine in other models, so maybe I should just use the same here. Thanks for the input. :-)

Comment: Maybe someone will share another approach so we will both learn something new ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating this little baby:

https://gist.github.com/carstengehling/6495127

Works quite nice for the purpose. A bit like rollout, though not user-specific and using AR instead of Redis.

Anyone else who finds this approach interesting, please let me know - I could do a gem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for [Rollout](https://github.com/bitlove/rollout).

Comment: If I read it correctly, Rollout is dependent on a Redis datastore. Since I don't use Redis (in this project), I would prefer something, that works with AR, or that simply is backend agnostic.